# Using LibXML in perl

Tags: xml, perl

I'm writing a script that does XML processing. The `use` is as follows:

```
use XML::LibXML;
```

But it doesn't compile:

```
Can't locate XML/LibXML.pm in @INC
```

Can anyone tell me which package do I need to install (running ubuntu). `libxml2` doesn't do the trick, nor does any of the `libxml-*-perl` packages.

Or, if possible, is there any better way for simple XML processing?

Comment: Installing [`libxml-libxml-perl`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/libxml-libxml-perl) didn't do the trick? That claims to be the right one for XML::LibXML.

Comment: There is no better way for processing XML in Perl than using `XML::LibXML`. Whether going with `XML::Simple` will be simpler or result in a horrible mess depends on factors like your XML input and your processing intentions. In my experience, it leads to a horrible mess in any but the simplest of simple situations.

Answer (score 12):

On Debian, it's named `libxml-libxml-perl`. (Generally speaking, Debian packages of Perl distributions are named `"lib".lc($perl_dist_name)."-perl"`.) I suspect it's the same on Ubuntu, being based on Debian.

`libxml2` is the underlying C++ library used by XML::LibXML, not XML::LibXML itself.

Answer (score 4):

There is a command named apt-file.

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
apt-file search LibXML.pm
```

The package you required is libxml-libxml-perl

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to install "XML::LibXML" on da Debian based OS is to use this command:

```
aptitude install libxml-libxml-perl
```

For me it works, if i get this Error you also get, by trying to get a script to work.

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install XML::LibXML'
```

should also work.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install the module?
try: `perl -MCPAN -e 'XML::LibXML'`

from the shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify which package you need for a given perl module by translating the module name to a pathname (e.g. XML::LibXML to XML/LibXML.pm), and doing an online package search for packages containing file paths ending with that, e.g.:

http://packages.debian.org/file:XML/LibXML.pm

or

http://packages.ubuntu.com/file:XML/LibXML.pm

On the results page, you can switch to searching a different release if you are using something other than the current default for package searches.